# Semantic Grid System, Media Query issue

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries, semantic.gs

I'm using the [Semantic Grid System](http://www.semantic.gs) to build a responsive site. However, something isn't quite right with the media queries that should obviously kick in once it hits a particular screen size.

I'll reference what i mean with their [example on the website](http://semantic.gs/examples/responsive/responsive.html) : if I view this on my iPhone for example, given that it is supposed to adjust to a single column structure on a mobile device, it still throws out the web version of the page. That is true for both Safari and Chrome on my iPhone. However, if I use the [RWD bookmarklet](http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr) to check it's appearance at different resolutions it appears as expected for the mobile resolution. Also, ironically, if I resize the page in Safari on my desktop it also adjusts accordingly once I get down to the approriate screen size, but not in Firefox.

The media query that it uses once it hits 720px is

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
#maincolumn,
#sidebar {
    .column(12);
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
}
```

and I might be wide of the mark here but I think that must be the issue. But given that this is directly from the semantic.gs website I don't think I have the expertise necessarily to question their own code.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you describe can be the result of not using the 'viewport' meta tag in your markup:

```
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
```

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

Comment: That fixed the mobile problem, thanks. It still doesn't snap correctly when I resize the webpage in Firefox on my desktop but, oddly, does in Chrome.